# How to switch to night in Sagus Cliffs?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

I am trying to figure out how to switch from day to night when in Sagus Cliff but there does not seem to be a way. Sleeping does not help, as you wake up during the day.

Yes, I am trying to talk to the Nychthemeron...

I know you can do this since a `Torment: Tides of Numenera | Interactive Quest Video` showed that it is possible to do just what I want. [The video in question paused at the right time.](https://youtu.be/Fjo1IyGCJVo?t=667),

Answer (score 3):

You can't switch to night normally. I was in the same boat, but could not find a way. There is one way to bring night to circus minor, but this requires you to damage the clock in the cultist camp, which means, you have to fail this quest to get nighttime.

From [Gamemaps](http://game-maps.com/TToN/Circus-Minor.asp)

> During the repair process you can permanently damage the clock
>   [Smashing, Lore Machinery]. I suggest not to do it, it is not the main
>   path of the quest. If you do it in Circus Minor will be permanently
>   night time . It is only posibility to talk to Nychthemeron at 06. You
>   will get a third possible solution for the Nychthemeron quest, it is
>   less interesting version of this quest.

However, it is possible to repair the clock afterwards.

Comment: It is in fact false, that the damage is permanent. You can repair the clock after smashing it.

Comment: Makes sense, come to think of it, you do get your specialization in the clock, so being unable to do this quest at all would severly hinder your character.

Comment: Hmm... no, you get the specialization thing immediately along with the breaking (just as you would by solving it correctly and interacting with the clock), you don't HAVE to repair it. But you certainly can can, as well as solving it correctly after repair.